# Accelerator (mnemonic key) are executed without pressing ALT key

Tags: .net, winforms, button

I'm experiencing some troubles using mnemonic keys in **Windows Forms**:

Simply having a form with a button, which uses ALT+s as the accelerator:

```
this.searchButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
this.searchButton.Text = "&search";
```

The button action is executed by simply pressing "s" (without pressing the ALT key).
I have checked some other applications, and the accelerator actions are only executed when the ALT key is pressed.

- Is this a .NET problem?
- How could address this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @leanne: It's .NET 2.0 but, I have also tested .NET 3 and .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 also failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behavior for .NET ("by design", they say).

Here is an article that should help with your issue - not simple or pretty to start out with, but once it's done, any shortcut keys you set up can be easily added:

[Building Keyboard Accelerators into .NET Windows Forms Applications - Code Guru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/keyboard/article.php/c4639)

Basically, this solution involves creating a class, loading a hash table, and overriding ProcessCmdKey to set up your own accelerator handler.

Answer (score 8):

You can alter this behavior by pasting this snippet into your form:

```
    protected override bool ProcessDialogChar(char charCode) {
        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.None) return false;
        return base.ProcessDialogChar(charCode);
    }
```

Not 100% sure this won't have other side-effects, keyboard handling in Winforms is convoluted to put it mildly.

Comment: Thanks, I did the same overriding ProcessMnemonicChar in the controls that receive acceleratos.