# Button Shortcut being executed without ALT key being pressed on Windows Forms

Tags: windows, forms

I'm testing out ways to create a shortcut for buttons. One of the ways I found was to add an ampersand (&) before the text property of the button so that when the user presses the ALT key with the first letter of the button, it should fire the button click event of that button. The problem is, the button click event is being fired even if the user presses only the corresponding letter, without the ALT key.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place a separate **KeyDown** Events for your controls. Below example implements quick shortcuts to ToolStripMenu, DatagridView.

```
Private Sub Shortcuts_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles _
            ToolStrip1.KeyDown, dgvToolStrip.KeyDown, dgvDataTable.KeyDown
        If (e.KeyCode And Not Keys.Modifiers) = Keys.F5 Then
            btnRefresh.PerformClick()
        ElseIf e.KeyValue = Keys.Enter Then
            btnOK.PerformClick()
        ElseIf e.KeyValue = Keys.F10 Then 'AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Shift Then
            btnShowAll.PerformClick()
        ElseIf (e.KeyCode And Not Keys.Modifiers) = Keys.P AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt Then
            btnShowImage.PerformClick()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as [Accelerator (mnemonic key) are executed without pressing ALT key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593892/accelerator-mnemonic-key-are-executed-without-pressing-alt-key)

This happens in controls where there is not edit capabilities, for example button, radio button, checkbox, etc. You can suppress this behavior creating a custom button, override the ProcessMnemonic method and return false if the alt key is not pressed.

```cs
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    protected override bool ProcessMnemonic(char charCode)
    {
        if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Alt) == Keys.None)
            return false;
        return base.ProcessMnemonic(charCode);
    }
}
```